# Cursor returns <sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x033A21E0> instead of returning the object itself

Tags: python, sqlite, cursor, execute

When i run this code on the db browser it displays the price, but it returns  the position on my console when i run it in python.

```
price = c.execute("SELECT Selling_Price FROM stock_records
        WHERE  Product_Name ='popcorn'")
print(price)
```

Comment: What else did you expect? You have to fetch your data from the cursor.

Answer (score 4):

You have to retrieve the item (or list of items) that have been returned. As an example:

```
price = c.execute("SELECT Selling_Price FROM stock_records
        WHERE  Product_Name ='popcorn'")
price = c.fetchone()
print(price)
```

More info can be found in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sqlite3.html).

Comment: i totally forgot about that than you.

Answer (score 0):

As @Matthias commented, `execute()` does not return query results directly; you must fetch the results from the cursor object.

Try this:

```
c.execute("SELECT Selling_Price FROM stock_records WHERE  Product_Name ='popcorn'")
print (c.fetchone())
```

If you expect the query to return more than one result row, use `fetchall()` instead of `fetchone()`.